# How do I create a TreeMap to store a keyword with its count and it's document id

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency

I am planning to store keywords from wiki dump. How do I create a TreeMap to store a keyword with its count and the document id where it is found. Also, I would want to store whether it is found the body, infobox, reference section etc.

I am unable to come with right data structure for it.

Comment: Kindly comment, If I was unable to clearly put forward my question, instead of out rightly down voting it.

Comment: *"store a keyword with its count and the document id where it is found"* Well, presumably a keyword may exist in multiple documents, so storing the count (across documents) and the (one and only) document id, is quite impossible. Please clarify exactly what you want, to yourself first, then to us if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: Count per document. Like keyword followed by document id and the count found in various sections of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you could use multiple `TreeMap`s, however it seems having a dedicated value class would be the better solution. Something like

```
public class KeyWordInfo {
    public enum Location {BODY, INFO_BOX; REF_SECTION};
    private int count = 0;
    private String documentId;
    private Set<Location> locations;
    public KeyWordInfo(int count, String documentId, Location... locations) {
        this.count = count;
        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.locations = EnumSet.of(locations);
    }
    //...getters, maybe setters
}

//usage
Map<String, KeyWordInfo> keyWordMap = new TreeMap<>();
keyWordMap.put("test", new KeyWordInfo(42,"doc0815",BODY,INFO_BOX));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a map storing information about keywords.
To start with you can create a map with a String as key and any Object type as value:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
myMap.put("myKey", new Object());
```

Then if needed you can change the value type "Object" to a new class you can define, with all the values that you require as members (count, documentId, locationFound, etc...)

Then the declaration of your map will be:

```
int count = 1;
String documentId = "myDocId";
String locationFound = "body";
Map<String, MyClass> myMap = new TreeMap<String, MyClass>();
myMap.put("myKey", new MyClass(count, documentId, locationFound));
```